# GKFriendRequestComposeViewController can't send request ('Send' grayed out)

Tags: swift, game-center, gamekit

I have attempted to implement the GKFriendRequestComposeViewController so that players can invite other players to Game Center from within my game app. I am able to deploy the GKFriendRequestComposeViewController and add PlayerIDs/emails to the recipient box. However, I am unable to press 'Send" and it is grayed out. I am still in Sandbox mode. What am I possibly missing here?

```
// helper function
func presentGKFriendRequestComposeViewController(viewController: UIViewController, message: String!) {

        self.presentingViewController = viewController        
        let friendRequestVC = GKFriendRequestComposeViewController()
        friendRequestVC.composeViewDelegate = self
        friendRequestVC.setMessage(message)
        viewController.presentViewController(friendRequestVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

// GKFriendRequestCompmoseViewControllerDelegate method
func friendRequestComposeViewControllerDidFinish(viewController: GKFriendRequestComposeViewController!) {

    self.presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that my invitation message string was too long. After shortening my message, the invitation could be sent. Hopefully Apple removes this limitation or documents it in the future. As of August 6, 2015, the message maximum was 140 characters.